# Voila not clearing output/dispalying new output

Tags: jupyter, ipywidgets, voila

I am trying to get an ipywidget button to change colour when clicked. I figured a way to do it as below

```
import ipywidgets as ipw
from ipywidgets import *
from IPython.display import display, HTML, clear_output
from IPython.display import display, HTML

pdf_btn = ipw.Button(description = 'Run PDF',button_style = 'danger', 
layout=Layout(width='150px', height='30px'))
new_btn = ipw.Button(description = 'PDF done',button_style = 'success', 
layout=Layout(width='150px', height='30px'))

HBox = ipw.HBox([pdf_btn])
HBox1 = ipw.HBox([new_btn])

def clear(b):
    clear_output()
    display(HBox1)

pdf_btn.on_click(clear)

display(HBox)
```

When inputting this code in Jupyter Notebook and rendering through Voila nothing happens.

Any ideas why ? And any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just update the button style maybe? Like so:

```py
import ipywidgets as ipw
from ipywidgets import *
from IPython.display import display, HTML, clear_output
from IPython.display import display, HTML

pdf_btn = ipw.Button(description = 'Run PDF',button_style = 'danger', 
layout=Layout(width='150px', height='30px'))

HBox = ipw.HBox([pdf_btn])

def clear(b):
    pdf_btn.button_style="success"
    pdf_btn.description="PDF done"

pdf_btn.on_click(clear)
display(HBox)
```

Note that your code fails in JupyterLab.
Voila is much more similar to JupyterLab's rendering machinery than the classic interface. For now, it is best to use JupyterLab in conjunction with developing for Voila. (Note that this will change soon as the underlying machinery for what is now the traditional Jupyter notebook interface will soon run on machinery more in line with JupyterLab, see [Build Jupyter Notebook v7 off of JupyterLab components](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html). A lot of the old code / approaches will then consistently not work and either interface will be as suitable for developing with Voila in mind.)

When your code fails in JupyterLab it logs that to the console, similar to as shown [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-output-in-log-rather-than-cell/13419?u=fomightez). I suspect you could follow Jason's advice, what I reference in my reply, which is [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/classic-notebook-instead-of-jupyterlab-on-mybinder-org/10714/6), **if you actually want the other button there**. (I guess I should say if you actually want the other HBox there since for some reason you have each button in a separate HBox in your code.) In other words, you'd need to add in how to handle the output from HBox1 correctly as part of the main output. Yours is going to the JupyterLab Log console as it is now.

So one option is to add HBox1 in as a displayed item, yet hide it initially:

```py
import ipywidgets as ipw
from ipywidgets import *
from IPython.display import display, HTML, clear_output
from IPython.display import display, HTML

pdf_btn = ipw.Button(description = 'Run PDF',button_style = 'danger', 
layout=Layout(width='150px', height='30px'))
new_btn = ipw.Button(description = 'PDF done',button_style = 'success', 
layout=Layout(width='150px', height='30px'))

HBox = ipw.HBox([pdf_btn])
HBox1 = ipw.HBox([new_btn])

HBox1.layout.visibility = 'hidden' #based on https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/674#issuecomment-234321603

def clear(b):
    HBox1.layout.visibility = 'visible'
    HBox.layout.display = 'none' #based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54134344/8508004 

pdf_btn.on_click(clear)

display(HBox)
display(HBox1)
```

You could also make an overarching vertical box for the items and then toggle which one it contains, similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54134344/8508004). This is the 'cleanest' option I'll list here, other than just having one button & changing the button itself:

```py
import ipywidgets as ipw
from ipywidgets import *
from IPython.display import display, HTML, clear_output
from IPython.display import display, HTML

pdf_btn = ipw.Button(description = 'Run PDF',button_style = 'danger', 
layout=Layout(width='150px', height='30px'))
new_btn = ipw.Button(description = 'PDF done',button_style = 'success', 
layout=Layout(width='150px', height='30px'))

HBox = ipw.HBox([pdf_btn])
HBox1 = ipw.HBox([new_btn])

vb = VBox(children = [HBox])

def clear(b):
    vb.children = [HBox1]

pdf_btn.on_click(clear)

display(vb)
```

('cleanest' in regards to it not creating extra space in the output area.)

Or combine the vertical box approach with the approach of toggling off via the layout settings:

```py
import ipywidgets as ipw
from ipywidgets import *
from IPython.display import display, HTML, clear_output
from IPython.display import display, HTML

pdf_btn = ipw.Button(description = 'Run PDF',button_style = 'danger', 
layout=Layout(width='150px', height='30px'))
new_btn = ipw.Button(description = 'PDF done',button_style = 'success', 
layout=Layout(width='150px', height='30px'))

HBox = ipw.HBox([pdf_btn])
HBox1 = ipw.HBox([new_btn])
HBox1.layout.visibility = 'hidden' #based on https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/674#issuecomment-234321603
vb = VBox(children = [HBox, HBox1])

def clear(b):
    HBox1.layout.visibility = 'visible'
    HBox.layout.display = 'none' #based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54134344/8508004 

pdf_btn.on_click(clear)

display(vb)
```

And if you want to fully [leverage Jupyter's display system further](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html), combine it with an overarching `out` so you can use `print()`, too:

```py
import ipywidgets as ipw
from ipywidgets import *
from IPython.display import display, HTML, clear_output
from IPython.display import display, HTML

out = widgets.Output()

pdf_btn = ipw.Button(description = 'Run PDF',button_style = 'danger', 
layout=Layout(width='150px', height='30px'))
new_btn = ipw.Button(description = 'PDF done',button_style = 'success', 
layout=Layout(width='150px', height='30px'))

HBox = ipw.HBox([pdf_btn])
HBox1 = ipw.HBox([new_btn])

vb = VBox(children = [HBox])

def clear(b):
    vb.children = [HBox1]
    with out:
        print('Enjoy!')

pdf_btn.on_click(clear)

with out:
    display(vb)
out
```

Comment: Great reply - many thanks. What's strange is that my initial code example runs fine for me in JupyterHub (I aassumed that was same as Jupyter Lab ?). 
Sorry on re reading your reply I understand your point. Awesome, thanks.

Comment: JupyterHub is way to serve multiple users sessions to use Jupyter notebook or JupyterLab via their browser. The site you are using may offer JupyterLab, too. You may want to ask. If you need an easy place to access JupyterLab, go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/voila) and click the `launch binder` badge **under JupyterLab**. A temporary session will spin up without needing you to sign in. You can test code like this there easily. It's a remote machine so you'll need to drag and drop in your `.ipynb` files.  And when you want to see how Voila will handle it, trigger sending the ...

Comment: <continued> ... notebook to the Voila rendering by hitting Voila icon along the toolbar just above the top of the notebook. You can also just go to the `View` menu along the top-most File menu and then select `Render Notebook with Voila`. (There is a way to open it as a tab there, too.) If using the notebook associated toolbar, the Voila icon is the little, mostly green circle with the Southwest quadrant colored yellow that is to the left of where you can toggle what type of code the cell is. On a small screen it may require you putting your cursor on that toolbar and scrolling to the left.

Comment: Keep in mind this session is very temporary. It will time out after about ten minutes of inactivity, and so you want to regularly download anything you make that is useful back to your local system. There is [a safety net of sorts](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/getting-your-notebook-after-your-binder-has-stopped/3268?u=fomightez) to help recover what is in the notebook if you absolutely need to. It's best to try it out so you have an idea how to use it in a pinch, but still not rely on it. The exact icons look different in JupyterLab but they are there on the notebook associated toolbar.

Comment: There is absolutely no way to get anything back if it goes inactive and you can no longer get to it. First, it is anonymous because you didn't sign it. And the ephemeral nature  is part of the privacy/security system that even the MyBinder people don't have access to instances that have died. By the way, to tie this back to your comment, what the MyBinder is using to serve the sessions to you in your browser is a very specialized JupyterHub. You can actually switch to the classic interface from JupyterLab there by looking under 'Help' on the File menu and selecting `Launch Classic Notebook`.