# IPython widgets not displaying properly within jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am attempting to display a IPython widget in jupyter lab by calling display(mywidget) but all I get is a log printout (the log printout is just a description of the object.) In jupyter notebook, the code all works fine. The problem in jupyter lab also only happens when I try to call the display function from within my own function.

This is the relevant section:

```
import IPython
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
try:
    import piplite
    await piplite.install(['ipywidgets'])
except ImportError:
    pass
import ipywidgets as widgets

def onhccchange(change):
    display(widgets.Button())

hcc = widgets.BoundedIntText(
    value=0,
    min=0,
    max=10,
    step=1,
    description='n = ',
    disabled=False
)

display(hcc)
hcc.observe(onhccchange, names='value')
```

Comment: Does the sentence 'The problem in jupyter lab also only happens when I try to call the display function from within my own function', mean that other ipywidgets work in your JupyterLab?

Comment: yes, when I try to display a widget from the main code block (not inside a function) it works fine, for example where I call display(hcc). That works.

Comment: Then that is at odds with the title of your post. But anyway, I see you have mention of `piplite()` in your code. Are you using JupyterLite or a full Python kernel?

Comment: I think you have a case similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73972010/8508004). Jupyter notebook classic is a lot more forgiving than JupyterLab. You have to assign output handling very specifically in JupyterLab. And how a button links to the output counts in that handling you need to specify.

Comment: I should add that it is worth learning the JupyterLab way of doing things as this is the way things are headed as the underlying machinery of the document-centric notebook, previously the classic Jupyter notebook, will be soon based on JupyterLab, see [here](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do after the button gets displayed.
Here's something closer that runs in JupyterLab in line with what I discuss in [this other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73972010/8508004) about updating without relying on [ipywidgets interactive function](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html?highlight=interactive#interactive):

```py
import IPython
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import *

hcc = widgets.BoundedIntText(
    value=0,
    min=0,
    max=10,
    step=1,
    description='n = ',
    disabled=False
)

new_btn = widgets.Button()

vb = VBox(children = [hcc])

def on_value_change(b):
    vb.children = [hcc,new_btn]

hcc.observe(on_value_change, names='value')
display(vb)
```

Your original code has the button going to the 'Log Console' in JupyterLab. That was what I mean about handling objects better and linking them to the output display in JupyterLab. You need to be more thorough in handling how output gets handled. If you see things going to the 'Log Console' in JupyterLab that is indication you aren't doing that.

(`from ipywidgets import *` was added to get the VBox easily. You may want to change that part.)

---

I should add that it is worth learning 'the JupyterLab way' of doing things as this is the way things are headed as the underlying machinery of the document-centric notebook, previously the classic Jupyter notebook, will be soon based on underlying JupyterLab machinery, see [here](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html).

Comment: thank you that worked! Just started learning all the ipython/notebook stuff for a project Im working on, good to know about the output stuff.

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of old code out there in regards to widgets.